# If $f$ is a continuous path in $\Bbb{R}^2$, and $f(0)\in B_1(0,0)$ and $f(1)\in B_1(10,10)$, how to prove that $f$ crosses the line $\{(x,y):x+y=5\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous, $f(0) \in B_{1}(0,0)$ and $f(1) \in B_{1}(10,10)$. Prove there exists $t \in [0,1]$ such that $f(t) \in \{(x,y): x+y=5\}$.

I am thinking we need to use extreme value theorem or intermediate value theorem. Which one and how?

Just for information $B_1$(x,y) is the circle of radius 1 around pt (x,y)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $g\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, $(x,y)\mapsto x+y-5$ is continuous and so is $g\circ f$.

**Second hint:** If $(x,y)\in B_r(a,b)$, then $a-r<x<a+r$ and $b-r<y<b+r$.

Comment: Well g(f(t)) = 0, still not sure what to do with your hint

Comment: f(0)= (x,y) implies -1<x< 1 and -1<y< 1 and f(1)= (x,y) implies 9<x<11 and 9<y<11. Not sure what to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my hint: consider the change of coordinates

$$u=x+y$$
$$v=x-y$$

Rephrasing the question in these coordinates:

> $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous, $f(0) \in B_{1}(0,0)$ and $f(1) \in B_{1}(20,0)$. Prove there exists $t \in [0,1]$ such that the first coordinate of $f(t)$ is 5.

Of course, this change of coordinates does nothing conceptually, but I think it is much clearer why the statement is true.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you show it? thanks

Comment: Think of the first coordinate of $f(t)$. Call it $u(t)$. It is a continuous function because it is a composition of $f$ with a projection. Now, $u(0)<5$ and $u(1)>5$. therefore, by the intermediate value theorem...